# SFSafariViewController crash

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

My iOS app crashes when I try to open url with `SFSafariViewController`. I use Sentry for logging and unfortunately it does not tell much about the crash:

> EXC_BREAKPOINT pas_segregated_size_directory

I can't reproduce the crash.

The code is very simple:

```
let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
present(vc, animated: true)
```

device: iPhone XR, iPhone SE (2nd generation).
os: iOS 15.5

I have the similar crash in other place too but instead of `SFSafariViewController` I use `WKWebView`. Sentry reports the same error message.

Comment: Probably that your url is http, try to set Allow Arbitrary Loads to yes in App Transport Security Settings.

Comment: It does not crash when I test on such urls.